# +constricted glottis includes ejectives and implosives, but Hayes only lists [ʔ] as [+cg] on his feature matrix. Why is that?

Tags: phonology

I've seen [+constricted glottis] described as encapsulating ejectives and implosives, but the feature matrix according to Hayes (2009) (that I pulled from his personal website over here: http://www.linguistics.ucla.edu/people/hayes/120a/features.xls) only lists the glottal stop as being [+c.g.]. Is there disagreement here? Or an error?

Comment: Or an omission: he doesn't include implosives, ejectives or glottalized sonorants in the file. Glottal stop is the only one he lists.

Comment: Although, disagreement is not impossible. There would be massive disagreement over his choice of features and decisions about binarity, so maybe he has another theory of implosives.

Comment: I'm beginning to think this may have been an oversight, even in his own book (Introductory Phonology) he lists +cg as including ejectives and implosives, but does not list them on his matrix http://udel.edu/~heinz/classes/2014/607/materials/readings/Hayes2009-04.pdf (page 90&95 here)

Comment: On p. 90 he lists glottal stop, ejectives, preglottalised (English syllable final /t/) and Korean tense C's as [+c.g.], and on the next page he employs a feature "+implosive" for implosives. There is no explanation for not likewise having a feature [+ejective], so all I can say is that this is an area of disgreement.